# Sorting string of small letters and capital letters in alphabetical order by using order by clause in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, collation

I am using mySQL and collation `utf8mb4_general_ci`.

I tried following query: 
`SELECT cid, cname from cust1 order by cname desc`

result is :

```
cid  cname     
3 bbb 
1 abc 
2 ABC
```

Is this sorting type (small letters first in descending order) is set in above collation?

Also if i run the following query:
`SELECT cid, cname from cust1 order by cname`

result is :

```
cid  cname     
1 abc 
2 ABC 
3 bbb
```

Again in ascending order small letters are coming first. I didn't understand this. Please explain it to me.

How can I change the database collation?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL is outputting the first entry it comes across, since in this case it considers "ABC" is the same as "abc".

You could try the ascii() function, like "order by cname desc, ascii(cname) desc".

I think you can change the character collation by using alter table like this:
"alter table cust1 character set latin1 collate latin1_swedish_ci", or whatever charset stuff you want.

Comment: Ascii defaults to ascii_general_ci, which is "Case Insensitive", hence will operate the same way.

Answer (score 0):

In database collation:
    a is bigger than A 
    A is bigger than b 
    b is bigger than B
For same letter,smaller letter is bigger than capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has `..._ci` collations.  These are, as the "ci" hints, Case Insensitive.  That is, `a` = `A`.  (`_ci` also strips accents.)

MySQL has `..._bin` collations.  These compare the bits.  Hence `a` is not the same as `A`.

Plan A:  Use `COLLATE utf8mb4_bin` on that column.

Plan B:  `ORDER BY cname DESC, id DESC` and `ORDER BY cname ASC, id ASC`.  That way, `id` will force a consistent order for rows 1 and 2.  (Not it won't force an order between `a` and `A`.

Plan C:  `ORDER BY cname DESC, cname COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DESC`.  (I have not verified that this syntax works.)  That should order 'a' and 'A' in a predictable way.